# Should [identification-request] questions be tagged with the series of origin once someone figures out what that is?

Tags: discussion, tags, retagging, identification-questions

For example, the currently top-voted [identification-request](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identification-request) question is [What manga is this image with a depressed girl from?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/4122/what-manga-is-this-image-with-a-depressed-girl-from). Should we tag that with [watamote](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/watamote)?

The only other StackExchange site I'm aware of that has an analog to our [identification-request](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identification-request) is [Scifi.SE](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/), with their [story-identification] tag. As per [this discussion](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/671/should-we-tag-story-identification-questions-with-the-name-of-the-author) on their meta, it seems their current position is to not retag once a source is identified.

Comment: If I'm not misunderstanding the question, this already has an answer [here](http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/a/450/274).

Comment: @Eric You're right; I didn't find that. I'll delete this question now.

Comment: No need to delete, we love duplicates :) They help us remember how much a topic was discussed, how requested a feature or a FAQ entry, etc. High rep users, vote to close as duplicates (I'm talking to you @Eric) OP and/or low rep users, flagging works just as great.

Answer (score -1):

Scifi.SE's situation differs from ours somewhat in that their [story-identification] questions almost invariably rely on remembered plot description and other relatively vague things, whereas our [identification-request](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identification-request) questions often come with a picture, which allows us to unambiguously identify a correct answer.

I think it would be good to retag with the source if either of the following are true:

1. The question contains an unambiguously-identifiable image.
2. The asker accepts an answer (or otherwise indicates that an answer is correct [e.g. by commenting, as some drive-by questioners are wont to do]).

Comment: What would be the point of tagging the question?